# Python : Are Async/Await based on Yield?

Tags: python, async-await, yield

If i really master coroutines with Yield, can i always avoid using Await/Async ?

In other words, are Await/Async kind of user friendly tools based on yield (which is less user friendly) ?

Comment: Yes. `async` used to be a `@asyncio.coroutine` dectorator of a function that yielded something, which now `awaits` something https://snarky.ca/how-the-heck-does-async-await-work-in-python-3-5/

Comment: Careful, though. Async programming based on `@asyncio.coroutine` belongs to python 3.5. On more modern version, there are more straightforward ways to handle async. But yes, your are right about the origin of this feature [source](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/#async-ios-roots-in-generators)